# find a final value in each row of a dataframe, keep that value, and replace all of the others

Tags: r

I am trying to automate some data formatting in R. I have multiple locations of individuals by date (each row is a one location, so one individual may have several rows).  I need to transpose the data so that each location date is a column and there is 1 row per individual. A 1 is entered in the column if the individual is found on that day, and a 0 if not.

Once this is done, I need to find the last observation that is a 1 in each row, retain that value as a 1, but change all other values in that row to 0.  I am able to find which rows and columns have the final value, but I haven't figured out how to include this function into a larger statement that will find these values and then replace the row values that don't meet the criteria.  I don't want to have to replace the values in each row individually.  I don't need output telling me which rows/columns meet my criteria.  The only reason I need to find them is replace other values in the dataframe.  Below is code for simulated data that I found on phidot.org that helped me construct the transposed dataframe (by J Laake). "Intervals" and "Occasions" were created to bin locations into different time periods as needed.

```
# create some dummy dates from tomorrow to 20 days from today
x = c(Sys.Date()+1:20)
# extract the year and change to numeric
as.numeric(format(x, "%Y"))
# you can also extract the month and day with
as.numeric(format(x, "%m"))
as.numeric(format(x, "%d"))


# create dummy capture data; id is animal and date is the date it was captured or recaptured
df=data.frame(id=floor(runif(100,1,50)),date=runif(100,0,5000)+as.Date("1980-01-01"))

#create some dummy date intervals that are approximately every 6 months
intervals=as.Date("1979-01-01")+seq(180,15*365,182.5)

# cut the dates into intervals
occasions=cut(df$date,intervals)

#create the count table with id for rows and years for columns
ch=with(df,table(id,occasions))
```

I get the table below (only showing the first 10 rows and 5 columns here):

```
ch[10:20,1:10]

occasions
# id   1979-06-30 1979-12-29 1980-06-29 1980-12-28 1981-06-29
#  1           0          1          0          0          0
#  2           0          1          0          0          0
#  3           0          0          0          0          0
#  4           0          0          0          0          0
#  5           0          0          0          0          0
#  6           0          0          0          0          0
#  7           0          0          0          0          0
#  9           0          0          0          0          0
#  10          0          1          0          0          0
```

Below is code I put together to find the last 1 in each row and assign it to an object:

```
last <- apply(ch,1,function(x){tail(which(x==1),1)})
last
```

But here is where I'm stuck.  I can't figure out how to keep those values in the data frame as 1's and replace all other values in the data frame with 0's.

Ultimately, in rows that have multiple ones, I'd like only the final 1 to show up and change the rest of the entries to 0.  So if I have the below table:

```
# id   1979-06-30 1979-12-29 1980-06-29 1980-12-28 1981-06-29
#  1           0          1          0          0          0
#  2           0          1          1          1          0
#  3           0          0          0          0          1
#  4           0          0          0          0          0
#  5           1          1          0          1          0
#  6           0          1          0          1          0
#  7           0          1          0          0          0
#  9           1          0          0          1          1
#  10          0          1          0          0          1
```

I'd like to change the table to look like this:

```
# id   1979-06-30 1979-12-29 1980-06-29 1980-12-28 1981-06-29
#  1           0          1          0          0          0
#  2           0          0          0          1          0
#  3           0          0          0          0          1
#  4           0          0          0          0          0
#  5           0          0          0          1          0
#  6           0          0          0          1          0
#  7           0          1          0          0          0
#  9           0          0          0          0          1
#  10          0          0          0          0          1
```

My current transposed data frame "ch" is 348 rows x 462 columns.  Each year data is added, so I'd like to automate this process in R, rather than having to format it in Excel each year and bring it into R for analyses.  I have looked at several questions and answers on this website, as well as phidot.org and the internet in general, and have not been able to figure this out after spending a few days on this.  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, building from where you left off with your table and using base R, you can do

```
ch.new <- t(apply(ch, 1, function(row){row[which.max(cumsum(row))] <- "max"; ifelse(row=="max", 1, 0)}))
ch.new[1:6,]
   occasions
id  1979-06-30 1979-12-29 1980-06-29 1980-12-28 1981-06-29 1981-12-28 1982-06-29 1982-12-28 1983-06-29 1983-12-28 1984-06-28
  1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          1          0
  5          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  6          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  8          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
   occasions
id  1984-12-27 1985-06-28 1985-12-27 1986-06-28 1986-12-27 1987-06-28 1987-12-27 1988-06-27 1988-12-26 1989-06-27 1989-12-26
  1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  2          0          0          0          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0
  4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  5          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  8          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
   occasions
id  1990-06-27 1990-12-26 1991-06-27 1991-12-26 1992-06-26 1992-12-25 1993-06-26
  1          0          0          1          0          0          0          0
  2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  5          0          0          0          0          0          1          0
  6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
  8          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily in `data.table` - instead of creating the intermediate matrix I find the max row directly in the data.frame:

```
#replicate your data
df=data.frame(id=floor(runif(100,1,50)),date=runif(100,0,5000)+as.Date("1980-01-01"))

#create some dummy date intervals that are approximately every 6 months
intervals=as.Date("1979-01-01")+seq(180,15*365,182.5)

# cut the dates into intervals (I added this as a new column)
df$occasions = as.Date(as.character(cut(df$date,intervals)))

# convert to data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

We can now find the last date found for each id:

```
df_last <- df[, .(last_date = max(occasions)), by = id]
```

We convert back to a factor so that all date intervals are represented:

```
df_last[, factor(as.character(last_date), levels = as.character(sort(unique(intervals))))]
```

We then cast this to get the desired matrix:

```
dcast(df_last, id ~ last_date, length, drop = FALSE, value.var = "last_date")

# Top Corner

   id 1979-12-29 1980-06-29 1980-12-28 1981-06-29 1981-12-28 1982-06-29 1982-12-28
 1:  1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
 2:  2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
 3:  3          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
 4:  4          0          0          0          0          1          0          0
 5:  5          0          1          0          0          0          0          0
 6:  6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
 7:  7          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
 8:  8          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
```